# aray_combine not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I expect `array_combine` to be able to take two arrays such as:

```
array('sample', 'sample_two', 'sample');
array(array('info', 'info_two'), array('bananas'), array('more_stuff'));
```

and produce:

```
array(
    'sample' => array(
         'info', 'info_two', 'more_stuff' 
    ),
    'sample_two' => array(
         'bananas'
    )
);
```

instead I get:

```
array(
    'sample' => array(
        'more_stuff' 
    ),
    'sample_two' => array(
         'bananas'
    )
);
```

Now I know php doesn't allow for duplicate key's so how can I use `array_combine` or some other method to achieve the desired array? It is safe to say that, the first array, will always match the second array in terms of layout. So you can draw lines between the values of array one and array two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not writing your own function?

```
function my_array_combine(array $keys, array $values) {
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
       $key = $keys[$i];
       if (!isset($result[$key])) {
          $result[$key] = array();
       }
       $result[$key] = array_merge($result[$key], $values[$i]);
    }
    return $result;
}
```